# Moving a Navigation Bar title

Tags: iphone

I was wondering if it's possible to move my navigationController title closer to the top of the bar? Right now it looks like this. [image]

I was thinking it would be

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[titleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,2, 2,100)]];
```

But I guess titleView has to be another view?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Give frame at the time of initialisation!

```
 UIView *iv = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,32,32)];
[iv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];


self.navigationItem.titleView = iv;
```

Comment: The frame gets smaller but it's not moving up.  I changed:    UIView *iv = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,32,32)];
    [iv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = iv;
    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"test title", @"test title");

Comment: Yeah 32, 32 is pretty small, you may need to adjust as necessary.